# Bootloop MIUI 12 after reboot (Xiaomi POCO X3 NFC)

Tags: boot-loop, logging, miui, miui-12

I got bootloop after MIUI 12 phone restart (Xiaomi POCO X3 NFC).
Using Magisk 21, TWRP v3.4.

I was able to get out the kernel logs, but can not identify where is the problem, what causes the bootloop.

Anybody can identify what causes the bootloop?

Here is the dmesg.log file content.

The full log is in pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/GcAJyz93

dmesg.log content (partial):

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.14.117-perf-g0abcc55 (builder@c4-miui-ota-bd081.bj) (clang version 8.0.12 for Android NDK) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 16 17:33:15 CST 2020
[    0.000000] Boot CPU: AArch64 Processor [51df805e]
[    0.000000] Powerup reason=0x80081
[    0.000000] Machine: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. SDMMAGPIE PM6150 IDP
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: OVERLAP DETECTED!
[    0.000000] disp_rdump_region@9c000000 (0x000000009c000000--0x000000009d800000) overlaps with cont_splash_region@9c000000 (0x000000009c000000--0x000000009d800000)
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: OVERLAP DETECTED!
[    0.000000] cont_splash_region@9c000000 (0x000000009c000000--0x000000009d800000) overlaps with dfps_data_region@9e300000 (0x000000009d700000--0x000000009d800000)
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x00000000ff800000, size 4 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node cdsp_region, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x00000001fa800000, size 36 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node mem_dump_region, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x00000000fd800000, size 32 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x00000000fcc00000, size 12 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node adsp_region, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x00000000fc400000, size 8 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node sp_region, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x00000000fb400000, size 16 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node qseecom_ta_region, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x00000000f5800000, size 92 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node secure_display_region, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000085700000, size 6 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node hyp_region@85700000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000085e00000, size 1 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node xbl_aop_mem@85e00000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000085fff000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node sec_apps_region@85fff000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000086000000, size 2 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node smem@86000000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000086200000, size 45 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node removed_region@86200000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x000000008ab00000, size 5 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node camera_region@8ab00000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x000000008b000000, size 132 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node modem_region@8b000000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000093400000, size 5 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node pil_video_region@93400000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000093900000, size 30 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node cdsp_regions@93900000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000095700000, size 30 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node pil_adsp_region@95700000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000097500000, size 1 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node wlan_msa_region@97500000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000097680000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node npu_region@97680000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000097700000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node ips_fw_region@97700000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000097710000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node ipa_gsi_region@97710000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x0000000097715000, size 0 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node gpu_region@97715000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x000000009e400000, size 20 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node qseecom_region@9e400000, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] Removed memory: created DMA memory pool at 0x000000009f800000, size 30 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node cdsp_sec_regions@0x9f800000, compatible id removed-dma-pool
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 1480425
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 6956 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 445161 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 16176 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1035264 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] psci: probing for conduit method from DT.
[    0.000000] psci: PSCIv1.1 detected in firmware.
[    0.000000] psci: Using standard PSCI v0.2 function IDs
[    0.000000] psci: MIGRATE_INFO_TYPE not supported.
[    0.000000] psci: SMC Calling Convention v1.1
[    0.000000] random: fast init done
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x94/0x558 with crng_init=1
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 23 pages/cpu s53656 r8192 d32360 u94208
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s53656 r8192 d32360 u94208 alloc=23*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 [0] 4 [0] 5 [0] 6 [0] 7 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 1457293
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: rcupdate.rcu_expedited=1 rcu_nocbs=0-7 console=ttyMSM0,115200n8 androidboot.hardware=qcom androidboot.console=ttyMSM0 androidboot.memcg=1 lpm_levels.sleep_disabled=1 video=vfb:640x400,bpp=32,memsize=3072000 msm_rtb.filter=0x237 service_locator.enable=1 androidboot.usbcontroller=a600000.dwc3 swiotlb=2048 loop.max_part=7 cgroup.memory=nokmem,nosocket androidboot.selinux=permissive androidboot.init_fatal_reboot_target=recovery buildvariant=eng androidboot.verifiedbootstate=orange androidboot.keymaster=1  androidboot.bootdevice=1d84000.ufshc androidboot.boot_devices=soc/1d84000.ufshc androidboot.serialno=d2c7e1d2 androidboot.product.hardware.sku=surya androidboot.cpuid=0xf9f4016b androidboot.multisim_config=dsds androidboot.dp=0x0 androidboot.baseband=msm msm_drm.dsi_display0=dsi_nt36672c_tianma_fhd_video_display: androidboot.fpsensor=gdx androidboot.lcmtype=dsi_nt36672c_tianma_fhd_video_display androidboot.dtbo_idx=10 androidboot.dtb_idx=9 androidboot.secur
[    0.000000] I am goodix fingerprint  --syhg
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes)
[    0.000000] software IO TLB: mapped [mem 0xf5400000-0xf5800000] (4MB)
[    0.000000] Memory: 5509764K/5921700K available (17918K kernel code, 2716K rwdata, 7256K rodata, 6144K init, 6808K bss, 207136K reserved, 204800K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=8, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU dyntick-idle grace-period acceleration is enabled.
[    0.000000]  All grace periods are expedited (rcu_expedited).
[    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] GICv3: no VLPI support, no direct LPI support
[    0.000000] GICv3: CPU0: found redistributor 0 region 0:0x0000000017a60000
[    0.000000]  Offload RCU callbacks from CPUs: 0-7.
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 and mmio timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (virt/virt).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000003] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000016] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.002044] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.002065] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.002075] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.002172] Security Framework initialized
[    0.002181] SELinux:  Initializing.
[    0.002238] SELinux:  Starting in permissive mode
[    0.002280] Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.002296] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.014225] ASID allocator initialised with 65536 entries
[    0.016320] Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.023875] MSM Memory Dump base table set up
[    0.023899] MSM Memory Dump apps data table set up
[    0.026399] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.035824] GICv3: CPU1: found redistributor 100 region 0:0x0000000017a80000
[    0.035870] CPU1: Booted secondary processor [51df805e]
[    0.045321] GICv3: CPU2: found redistributor 200 region 0:0x0000000017aa0000
[    0.045355] CPU2: Booted secondary processor [51df805e]
[    0.054822] GICv3: CPU3: found redistributor 300 region 0:0x0000000017ac0000
[    0.054853] CPU3: Booted secondary processor [51df805e]
[    0.064412] GICv3: CPU4: found redistributor 400 region 0:0x0000000017ae0000
[    0.064442] CPU4: Booted secondary processor [51df805e]
[    0.074092] GICv3: CPU5: found redistributor 500 region 0:0x0000000017b00000
[    0.074123] CPU5: Booted secondary processor [51df805e]
[    0.084544] CPU features: Unsupported CPU feature variation detected.
[    0.084578] GICv3: CPU6: found redistributor 600 region 0:0x0000000017b20000
[    0.084630] CPU6: Booted secondary processor [51df804e]
[    0.094922] GICv3: CPU7: found redistributor 700 region 0:0x0000000017b40000
[    0.094977] CPU7: Booted secondary processor [51df804e]
[    0.095224] smp: Brought up 1 node, 8 CPUs
[    0.095253] SMP: Total of 8 processors activated.
[    0.095259] CPU features: detected feature: GIC system register CPU interface
[    0.095262] CPU features: detected feature: Privileged Access Never
[    0.095266] CPU features: detected feature: User Access Override
[    0.095269] CPU features: detected feature: 32-bit EL0 Support
[    0.095274] CPU features: detected: Hardware dirty bit management
[    0.095900] CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL1
[    0.095944] alternatives: patching kernel code
[    0.148958] Registered cp15_barrier emulation handler
[    0.148978] Registered setend emulation handler
[    0.149380] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.149407] futex hash table entries: 2048 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.154482] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.155358] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.157729] schedtune: configured to support 6 boost groups
[    0.158659] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.158700] cpuidle: using governor qcom
[    0.158828] NET: Registered protocol family 42
[    0.166431] vdso: 2 pages (1 code @         (ptrval), 1 data @         (ptrval))
[    0.166446] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.167668] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic allocations
[    0.168298] Failed to create IPC log0
[    0.168306] Failed to create IPC log1
[    0.168313] Failed to create IPC log2
[    0.168319] Failed to create IPC log3
[    0.168325] Failed to create IPC log4
[    0.168475] exit: IPA_USB init success!
[    0.168794] ramoops: dump_mem_sz=1048576,cxt->record_size=524288,cxt->size=4194304,cxt->console_size=1048576,cxt->ftrace_size=0,cxt->pmsg_size=2097152
[    0.179668] pstore: using zlib compression
[    0.180614] console [pstore-1] enabled
[    0.180712] pstore: Registered ramoops as persistent store backend
[    0.180727] ramoops: attached 0x400000@0x9d800000, ecc: 0/0
[    0.181939] msm-sn-fuse 786134.snfuse: serial num: f9f4016b buqingshuai
[    0.181956] msm-sn-fuse 786134.snfuse: fuse state: 0x0,0x0,0x0 buqingshuai
[    0.181969] msm-sn-fuse 786134.snfuse: SN interface initializedbuqingshuai
[    0.183946] sps:sps is ready.
[    0.186079] unable to find DT imem DLOAD mode node
[    0.187478] unable to find DT imem EDLOAD mode node
[    0.189987] msm_watchdog 17c10000.qcom,wdt: wdog absent resource not present
[    0.191569] msm_watchdog 17c10000.qcom,wdt: MSM Watchdog Initialized
[    0.192460] platform soc:mem_dump: assigned reserved memory node mem_dump_region
[    0.231609] platform soc:qcom,smem: assigned reserved memory node smem@86000000
[    0.232167] platform soc:qcom,msm-adsprpc-mem: assigned reserved memory node adsp_region
[    0.239512] platform 86d00000.qseecom: assigned reserved memory node qseecom_region@9e400000
[    0.240519] platform 62400000.qcom,lpass: assigned reserved memory node pil_adsp_region@95700000
[    0.241651] spmi spmi-0: PMIC arbiter version v5 (0x50000000)
[    0.241682] platform 8300000.qcom,turing: assigned reserved memory node cdsp_regions@93900000
[    0.241921] platform 4080000.qcom,mss: assigned reserved memory node modem_region@8b000000
[    0.242065] platform aae0000.qcom,venus: assigned reserved memory node pil_video_region@93400000
[    0.242197] platform 9800000.qcom,npu: assigned reserved memory node npu_region@97680000
[    0.243151] (NULL device *): msm_gsi_probe:4526 failed to create IPC log, continue...
[    0.247256] LCDB: qpnp_lcdb_regulator_probe: Failed to parse dt rc=-517
[    0.247894] platform soc:qcom,ipa_fws: assigned reserved memory node ips_fw_region@97700000
[    0.248036] spmi spmi-0: pmic_arb_wait_for_done: transaction failed (0x3)
[    0.265621] sdmmagpie-pinctrl 3400000.pinctrl: invalid resource
[    0.272544] rpmh_regulator_probe: smpf1: could not find RPMh address for resource
[    0.272817] rpmh_regulator_probe: smpf2: could not find RPMh address for resource
[    0.280209] pm6150_l17: supplied by pm6150_l11
[    0.280705] pm6150_l18: Bringing 1uV into 1696000-1696000uV
[    0.287962] rpmh_regulator_probe: ldof1: could not find RPMh address for resource
[    0.288178] rpmh_regulator_probe: ldof2: could not find RPMh address for resource
[    0.288383] rpmh_regulator_probe: ldof4: could not find RPMh address for resource
[    0.288590] rpmh_regulator_probe: ldof5: could not find RPMh address for resource
[    0.288791] rpmh_regulator_probe: ldof6: could not find RPMh address for resource
[    0.288989] rpmh_regulator_probe: ldof7: could not find RPMh address for resource
[    0.298302] OF: amba_device_add() failed (-16) for /soc/cti@6867000
[    0.331183] gpu_cx_gdsc: supplied by pm6150l_s2_level
[    0.333167] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 572000 uv) on cpu0
[    0.333515] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (1804800000 Hz, 796000 uv) on cpu0
[    0.333581] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 572000 uv) on cpu1
[    0.333912] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (1804800000 Hz, 796000 uv) on cpu1
[    0.333987] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 572000 uv) on cpu2
[    0.334314] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (1804800000 Hz, 796000 uv) on cpu2
[    0.334391] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 572000 uv) on cpu3
[    0.334715] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (1804800000 Hz, 796000 uv) on cpu3
[    0.334774] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 572000 uv) on cpu4
[    0.335116] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (1804800000 Hz, 796000 uv) on cpu4
[    0.335179] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 572000 uv) on cpu5
[    0.335520] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (1804800000 Hz, 796000 uv) on cpu5
[    0.335599] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 572000 uv) on cpu6
[    0.336079] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (2304000000 Hz, 920000 uv) on cpu6
[    0.336163] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 572000 uv) on cpu7
[    0.336645] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (2304000000 Hz, 920000 uv) on cpu7
[    0.336956] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 568000 uv) on soc:qcom,cpu0-cpu-l3-lat
[    0.336969] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 568000 uv) on soc:qcom,cpu6-cpu-l3-lat
[    0.336980] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (300000000 Hz, 568000 uv) on soc:qcom,cdsp-cdsp-l3-lat
[    0.338091] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (1459200000 Hz, 756000 uv) on soc:qcom,cpu0-cpu-l3-lat
[    0.338105] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (1459200000 Hz, 756000 uv) on soc:qcom,cpu6-cpu-l3-lat
[    0.338118] clk: add_opp: Set OPP pair (1459200000 Hz, 756000 uv) on soc:qcom,cdsp-cdsp-l3-lat
[    0.339104] sched-energy: Sched-energy-costs installed from DT
[    0.340268] cpufreq: driver osm-cpufreq up and running
[    0.340293] clk: clk_cpu_osm_driver_probe: OSM CPUFreq driver inited
[    0.344594] cam_cc-sdmmagpie ad00000.qcom,camcc: Registered Camera CC clocks
[    0.345114] qmp-aop-clk soc:qcom,aopclk: Registered clocks with AOP
[    0.346279] clk-rpmh soc:qcom,rpmh: Registered RPMh clocks
[    0.347430] disp_cc-sdmmagpie af00000.qcom,dispcc: Registered Display CC clocks
[    0.353445] gcc-sdmmagpie 100000.qcom,gcc: Registered GCC clocks
[    0.354360] gpu_cc_gmu_clk_src: set OPP pair(19200000 Hz: 49 uV) on 506a000.qcom,gmu
[    0.354379] gpu_cc_gmu_clk_src: set OPP pair(200000000 Hz: 49 uV) on 506a000.qcom,gmu
[    0.354526] gpu_cc_gx_gfx3d_clk_src: set OPP pair(180000000 Hz: 49 uV) on 5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0
[    0.354593] gpu_cc_gx_gfx3d_clk_src: set OPP pair(700000000 Hz: 385 uV) on 5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0
[    0.354619] gpu_cc_gx_gfx3d_clk_src: set OPP pair(825000000 Hz: 417 uV) on 5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0
[    0.354677] gpu_cc-sdmmagpie 5090000.qcom,gpucc: Registered GPU CC clocks
[    0.355933] video_cc-sdmmagpie ab00000.qcom,videocc: Registered Video CC clocks
[    0.357753] KPI: Bootloader start count = 61534
[    0.357757] KPI: Bootloader end count = 267083
[    0.357760] KPI: Bootloader display count = 1438326266
[    0.357762] KPI: Bootloader load kernel count = 2470170460
[    0.357766] KPI: Kernel MPM timestamp = 285504
[    0.357768] KPI: Kernel MPM Clock frequency = 32768
[    0.357777] socinfo_print: v0.15, id=365, ver=1.0, raw_id=230, raw_ver=0, hw_plat=34, hw_plat_ver=65536
[    0.357777]  accessory_chip=0, hw_plat_subtype=0, pmic_model=65576, pmic_die_revision=131072 foundry_id=3 serial_number=4193517931 num_pmics=2 chip_family=0x60 raw_device_family=0x6 raw_device_number=0xc nproduct_id=0x40f num_clusters=0x1 ncluster_array_offset=0xb0 num_defective_parts=0xc ndefective_parts_array_offset=0xb4 nmodem_supported=0xff
[    0.357842] Minidump: Enabled with max number of regions 200
[    0.357875] Failed to setup PIL ipc logging
[    0.357878] msm_bus_fabric_rpmh_init_driver
[    0.357960] msm_bus: Probe started
[    0.358208] msm_bus_device 16e0000.ad-hoc-bus: Bus type is missing
[    0.358239] msm_bus_device 16e0000.ad-hoc-bus: Bus type is missing
[    0.358246] msm_bus_device 16e0000.ad-hoc-bus: Bus type is missing
[    0.358267] msm_bus_device 16e0000.ad-hoc-bus: Bus type is missing
[    0.358948] msm_bus: DT Parsing complete
[    0.361009] msm_bus_fab_init_noc_ops: Invalid Bus type
[    0.361083] msm_bus_fab_init_noc_ops: Invalid Bus type
[    0.361095] msm_bus_fab_init_noc_ops: Invalid Bus type
[    0.361141] msm_bus_fab_init_noc_ops: Invalid Bus type
[    0.366739] uw_ldo_ois_drv_regulator: supplied by pm6150l_bob
[    0.367341] arm-smmu 5040000.arm,smmu-kgsl:  non-coherent table walk
[    0.367346] arm-smmu 5040000.arm,smmu-kgsl:  (IDR0.CTTW overridden by FW configuration)
[    0.367350] arm-smmu 5040000.arm,smmu-kgsl:  stream matching with 5 register groups
[    0.368707] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 161 dest 627
[    0.368776] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 1 apps_smmu
[    0.368873] arm-smmu 15000000.apps-smmu:     non-coherent table walk
[    0.368878] arm-smmu 15000000.apps-smmu:     (IDR0.CTTW overridden by FW configuration)
[    0.368882] arm-smmu 15000000.apps-smmu:     stream matching with 79 register groups
[    0.369588] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 161 dest 627
[    0.369645] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 2 apps_smmu
[    0.369744] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 161 dest 627
[    0.369798] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 3 apps_smmu
[    0.369871] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 22 dest 773
[    0.369903] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 4 mnoc_hf_0_tbu
[    0.369980] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 22 dest 773
[    0.370007] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 5 mnoc_hf_1_tbu
[    0.370100] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 137 dest 772
[    0.370131] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 6 mnoc_sf_0_tbu
[    0.370188] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 154 dest 10076
[    0.370208] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 7 apps_smmu
[    0.370283] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 161 dest 627
[    0.370340] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 8 apps_smmu
[    0.370420] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 161 dest 627
[    0.370473] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 9 apps_smmu
[    0.370795] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.370921] qcom,qpnp-misc c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm6150@0:qcom,misc@900: probe successful
[    0.371201] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.371239] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.371247] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.371345] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.371546] usb_phy_generic soc:usb_nop_phy: soc:usb_nop_phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.371790] xiaomi_touch_probe enter
[    0.371793] xiaomi_touch_parse_dt touch,name:xiaomi-touch
[    0.371819] xiaomi_touch_probe over
[    0.371935] qcom,qpnp-power-on c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm6150@0:qcom,power-on@800: PMIC@SID0 Power-on reason: Triggered from Hard Reset and 'cold' boot
[    0.371958] qcom,qpnp-power-on c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm6150@0:qcom,power-on@800: PMIC@SID0: Power-off reason: Triggered from KPDPWR_N (Long Power Key Hold)
[    0.372053] input: qpnp_pon as /devices/platform/soc/c440000.qcom,spmi/spmi-0/spmi0-00/c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm6150@0:qcom,power-on@800/input/input0
[    0.372835] qcom,qpnp-power-on c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm6150l@4:qcom,power-on@800: PMIC@SID4 Power-on reason: Triggered from PON1 (Secondary PMIC) and 'cold' boot
[    0.372859] qcom,qpnp-power-on c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm6150l@4:qcom,power-on@800: PMIC@SID4: Power-off reason: Triggered from SOFT (Software)
[    0.373002] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.373010] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.373022] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.373024] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.373029] PTP clock support registered
[    0.374398] thermal_sys: VIRTUAL-SENSOR board sensor: 
[    0.374401] board sensor: VIRTUAL-SENSOR
[    0.375507] tsens_tm_probe : unable to create IPC Logging 0 for tsens 0x000000000c263000
[    0.375509] tsens_tm_probe : unable to create IPC Logging 1 for tsens 0x000000000c263000
[    0.375512] tsens_tm_probe : unable to create IPC Logging 2 for tsens 0x000000000c263000
[    0.376266] tsens_tm_probe : unable to create IPC Logging 0 for tsens 0x000000000c265000
[    0.376269] tsens_tm_probe : unable to create IPC Logging 1 for tsens 0x000000000c265000
[    0.376272] tsens_tm_probe : unable to create IPC Logging 2 for tsens 0x000000000c265000
[    0.376697] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.377404] platform soc:qcom,ion:qcom,ion-heap@27: assigned reserved memory node qseecom_region@9e400000
[    0.377439] platform soc:qcom,ion:qcom,ion-heap@19: assigned reserved memory node qseecom_ta_region
[    0.377469] platform soc:qcom,ion:qcom,ion-heap@13: assigned reserved memory node sp_region
[    0.377495] platform soc:qcom,ion:qcom,ion-heap@10: assigned reserved memory node secure_display_region
[    0.377585] ION heap system created
[    0.377676] ION heap qsecom created at 0x000000009e400000 with size 1400000
[    0.377683] ION heap qsecom_ta created at 0x00000000fb400000 with size 1000000
[    0.377689] ION heap spss created at 0x00000000fc400000 with size 800000
[    0.377696] ION heap secure_display created at 0x00000000f5800000 with size 5c00000
[    0.389140] platform soc:qcom,ion:qcom,ion-heap@14: ion_secure_carveout: creating heap@0x9f800000, size 0x1e00000
[    0.389146] ION heap secure_carveout created
[    0.389167] ION heap secure_heap created
[    0.389790] qupv3_geni_se 8c0000.qcom,qupv3_0_geni_se: geni_se_probe Failed to allocate log context
[    0.389957] iommu: Adding device 8c0000.qcom,qupv3_0_geni_se:qcom,iommu_qupv3_0_geni_se_cb to group 0
[    0.390031] qupv3_geni_se ac0000.qcom,qupv3_1_geni_se: geni_se_probe Failed to allocate log context
[    0.390168] iommu: Adding device ac0000.qcom,qupv3_1_geni_se:qcom,iommu_qupv3_1_geni_se_cb to group 1
[    0.390473] PMIC@SID0: PM6150 v2.0 options: 0, 0, 0, 0
[    0.390571] PMIC@SID4: PM8150L v3.0 options: 0, 0, 0, 0
[    0.390608] spmi spmi-0: pmic_arb_wait_for_done: transaction failed (0x3)
[    0.390610] read failed rc=-5
[    0.390612] Invalid REVID peripheral type: 00
[    0.390618] qcom,qpnp-revid: probe of c440000.qcom,spmi:qcom,pm8009@a:qcom,revid@100 failed with error -22
[    0.391187] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 90 dest 512
[    0.391351] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 90 dest 585
[    0.391404] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 1 dest 676
[    0.391494] register_client_adhoc:find path.src 143 dest 777
[    0.391523] register_client_adhoc:Client handle 10 ipa
[    0.392931] ipa ipa3_smp2p_probe:7956 fail to get smp2p clk resp bit -517
[    0.393436] iommu: Adding device soc:ipa_smmu_ap to group 2
[    0.393628] iommu: Adding device soc:ipa_smmu_wlan to group 3
[    0.393930] iommu: Adding device soc:ipa_smmu_uc to group 4
[    0.396227] ipa ipa3_smp2p_probe:7956 fail to get smp2p clk resp bit -517
[    0.400456] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.401240] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    0.401354] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    0.401358] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    0.401379] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    0.401386] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    0.401431] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    0.402046] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.402051] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
...
```

Comment: From TWRP, [uninstall magisk](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html), to rule out Magisk modules creating this //If it works update to Magisk v23 and add modules one by one to identify culprit - this is a guess and not based on logs

Comment: Thanks for this info. Finally I solved by reflashing the original boot.img.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the boot image.

Solution steps:

1. I searched for exact POCO X3 NFC rom .TGZ file, and found it here:
   https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/miui/surya/stable/V12.0.7.0.QJGEUXM/
2. I downloaded the following file:
   surya_eea_global_images_V12.0.7.0.QJGEUXM_20201221.0000.00_10.0_eea_6c03e13a9f.tgz
3. Extracted the "boot.img" file
4. Using
   adb reboot bootloader
   rebooted phone into bootloader mode.
5. Using
   fastboot flash boot boot.img
   finally I flashed the original boot.img
6. Rebooted with long press power button
7. Booted fine into MIUI.